# can I assume that the .cache directory exists?

Tags: linux, caching, posix

I'd like to cache some files in `$HOME/.cache`, but I don't know under what OSes I can assume that it already exists. Can I try to create it myself if it does not, or is that an error? What entity creates it? Is the location of `.cache` standardized and by what standard?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### (Linux) File System Hierarchy

The linux [file system hierarchy (`man hier`)](http://linux.die.net/man/7/hier) does not imply  any `$HOME/.cache` directory. From that man page, highlighting added by me:

> **`/home`**
>
> On machines with home directories for users, these are usually
>   beneath this directory, directly or not. The structure of this
>   directory *depends on local administration decisions*.

#### freedesktop.org Specifications

The `.config` and `.cache` directories are [specified by freedesktop.org as reasonable defaults](http://standards.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html) to the environment variables `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME` and `$XDG_CACHE_HOME`. Quoted from these specifications, again highlighting is added by me:

> `$XDG_CACHE_HOME` defines the base directory relative to which user specific non-essential data files should be stored. If `$XDG_CACHE_HOME` is either not set or empty, *a default equal to `$HOME/.cache`* should be used.

To follow their specifications, you might want to read `$XDG_CACHE_HOME` first, and if not set use `$HOME/.cache` and create it, if necessary. You will very often encounter these variables not set – in fact, it is not set on any of my machines.

Comment: on my machine, both `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME` and `$XDG_CACHE_HOME` are empty.

Comment: Added some quote to highlight their proposals for reasonable defaults (which, in fact, is `$HOME/.cache`).